# ElasticSearch Ruby returning results without ElasticSearch running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch

I'm using the new ElasticSearch Ruby gems:

```
gem 'elasticsearch'
gem 'elasticsearch-model'
gem 'elasticsearch-rails'
```

I'm a bit puzzled by the fact that it's returning results, without having any instance of ElasticSearch running...

For instance, I do:

`Tag.search("stackoverflow").results.first`

And it actually returns an `#<Elasticsearch::Model::Response::Result>` instance, containing "stackoverflow".

Here a gif of the issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7htH.gif

Where does it come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually had setup the elasticsearch client to connect to bonsai.io...

```
Elasticsearch::Model.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new({
  host: bonsai_host
})
```

I did it when deploying to heroku, and completely forgot.

Answer (score 0):

To test whether `ElasticSearch` is running or not, try this in terminal:

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200'
```

The response will be similar to this:

```
{
  "ok" : true,
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Destroyer, The",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "0.90.7",
    "build_hash" : "36897d07dadcb70886db7f149e645ed3d44eb5f2",
    "build_timestamp" : "2013-11-13T12:06:54Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.5.1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Comment: I know, and it's not running! That's what I find really weird.